# No puedo llamar un metodo desde otra clase

Tags: java, clase, herencia

intento llamar un método de la clase padre hacia una clase hija y no me deja, me salta error, estan en el mismo paquete, alguien sabe por qué es o que estoy haciendo mal?? la verdad soy nueva en esto y estuve buscando informacion de muchos videos pero estoy muy confundida al respecto, las clases no son abstractas.

El mensaje que me sale del error es este: constructor CuentaBase in class cannot be applied to given types;
required: double, int string, string, string.
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length.

Esta es la clase padre:

```
package paquete_1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CuentaBase {
protected double depositar;
private int opcion;
private int edad;
private String nombre, apellido, curp, direccion;
private double suma, resta;
private double retirar, montoActual = 1000;
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

public CuentaBase(double depositar, int edad, String nombre, String apellido, String curp, String direccion) {
    this.depositar = depositar;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.curp = curp;
    this.direccion = direccion;
}


public double getmontoActual() {
    return montoActual;
}

public double getDepositar() {
    System.out.print("Cuanto desea depositar?: ");
    depositar = entrada.nextDouble();
    return depositar;
}

public double getRetirar() {
    System.out.println("Digite lo que desea retirar. ");
    retirar = entrada.nextDouble();
    return retirar;
}

public double getResta() {
    resta = montoActual - retirar;
    return resta;
}

public double getSuma() {
    suma = montoActual + depositar;
    return suma;
}

public double getsumaInteres() {
    System.out.println("Tiene un monto de salgo negativo: " + -montoActual * 1.15);
    return montoActual;
}

public double getinvertir() {
    System.out.println("Tiene un monto de: " + montoActual * 1.10);
    return montoActual;
}

//este es el metodo que quiero llamar hacia TarjetaDebito
public void leerDatos() {
    System.out.print("Ingrese sus datos: ");
    System.out.print("Nombre: ");
    nombre = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.print("CURP: ");
    curp = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Direccion: ");
    direccion = entrada.nextLine();
}
```

}

Aqui la clase hija

```
public class TarjetaDebito extends CuentaBase {
private int opcion2;
public TarjetaDebito(double depositar, int edad, String nombre, String apellido, String curp, String direccion) {
    super(depositar, edad, nombre, apellido, curp, direccion);
}

public void operaciones () {
    do {
        System.out.println("Porfavor seleccione una opción:");
        System.out.println("    1. Ver monto actual: ");
        System.out.println("    2. Abrir una tarjeta de credito");
        System.out.println("    3. Depositar");
        System.out.println("    4. Retirar");
        System.out.println("    5. Salir");
        opcion2 = entrada.nextInt();
        switch (opcion2) {
            case 1: getmontoActual();break;
            case 2: 
                //Aqui es donde me sale error, no me deja llamar el metodo leerDatos
                CuentaBase ob1= new CuentaBase();
                ob1.leerDatos();
            case 3: getDepositar();
                System.out.println("Su saldo actual es de: " + getSuma()); break;
            case 4:
                getRetirar();
                System.out.println("Su saldo actual es de: " + getResta());break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Gracias por su visita, vuelva pronto. ");break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("No existe la opcion, intente de nuevo. ");break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } while (opcion2 < 1 || opcion2 > 5);
}
```

}

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El código va como texto no en imágenes.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y pon el código como texto. Además no se ve la definición de la clase `CuentaBase`. ¿Es una clase abstracta? Las clases abstractas no se pueden instanciar.

Comment: Gracias, acabo de actualizar y puse el codigo.

Comment: El constructor de `CuentaBase` pide parámetros... no le estás pasando nada. Lo has declarado así: `public CuentaBase(double depositar, int edad, String nombre, String apellido, String curp, String direccion)`, no puedes usarlo así: `new CuentaBase()` <-- Necesita los mismos parámetros que le declaraste...

Comment: Te da error porque no has declarado el constructor vacío de la clase CuentaBase. Si no declaras un constructor, entonces se usa el constructor vacío. PERO si defines un constructor con parámetros, entonces deberás declarar el constructor vacío si lo quieres.

Comment: Gracias, no logre resolverlo asi que mejor opte por ponerlo en protected.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con metodo, no puedo llamar un metodo desde otra clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/541180/problema-con-metodo-no-puedo-llamar-un-metodo-desde-otra-clase) No dupliques preguntas por favor

Answer (score 0):

Debes añadir el constructor vacío en la clase **CuentaBase**

```
public CuentaBase() {}
```

Comment: En ese caso debería añadir, además, los *setters* para todos los atributos. La otra opción es usar el constructor que ya tiene creado donde se reciben como parámetros los valores a guardar