# Problema con metodo, no puedo llamar un metodo desde otra clase

Tags: java, herencia

tengo un problema en una clase, quiero llamar un metodo desde el main, pero me sale error y no se como proceder aqui, alguien me podria ayudar? ando muy perdida. :/

En el error que me aparece es este: "cannot find symbol"

```
   TarjetaDebito ob2= new TarjetaDebito(nombre, apellido, curp, direccion);
   ob2.operaciones(); break;
```

y cuando quito el nombre, apellido, curp, direccion me aparece este mensaje:
in class cannot be applied to given types; required: String, String, String, string. found: no arguments reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length.

```
package paquete_1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CuentaBase {

protected double depositar;
private int opcion;
protected String nombre, apellido, curp, direccion;
private double suma, resta;
private double retirar, montoActual = 1000;
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

public CuentaBase(String nombre, String apellido, String curp, String direccion) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.curp = curp;
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

   public void leerDatos() {
    System.out.print("Ingrese sus datos: ");
    System.out.print("Nombre: ");
    nombre = entrada.nextLine();      
    System.out.print("Apellido: ");
    apellido = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.print("CURP: ");
    curp = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Direccion: ");
    direccion = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Sus datos han sido ingresados correctamente, regrese pronto. ");
    direccion = entrada.nextLine();
}

public double getmontoActual() {
    return montoActual;
}

public double getDepositar() {
    System.out.print("Cuanto desea depositar?: ");
    depositar = entrada.nextDouble();
    return depositar;
}

public double getRetirar() {
    System.out.println("Digite lo que desea retirar. ");
    retirar = entrada.nextDouble();
    return retirar;
}

public double getResta() {
    resta = montoActual - retirar;
    return resta;
}

public double getSuma() {
    suma = montoActual + depositar;
    return suma;
}

public double getsumaInteres() {
    System.out.println("Tiene un monto de saldo negativo: " + -montoActual * 1.15);
    return montoActual;
}

public double getinvertir() {
    System.out.println("Tiene un monto de: " + montoActual * 1.10);
    return montoActual;
} 
}
```

Clase tarjetaDebito

```
package paquete_1;
public class TarjetaDebito extends CuentaBase {
private int opcion2;
public TarjetaDebito(String nombre, String apellido, String curp, String direccion) {
    super(nombre, apellido, curp, direccion);
 
}
//Metodo que intento llamar al main
public void operaciones () {
    do {
        System.out.println("Porfavor seleccione una opción:");
        System.out.println("    1. Ver monto actual: ");
        System.out.println("    2. Abrir una tarjeta de credito");
        System.out.println("    3. Depositar");
        System.out.println("    4. Retirar");
        System.out.println("    5. Salir");
        opcion2 = entrada.nextInt();
        switch (opcion2) {
            case 1: getmontoActual();break;
            case 2: 
                CuentaBase ob1= new CuentaBase(nombre, apellido, curp, direccion);
                ob1.leerDatos(); break;

            case 3: getDepositar();
                System.out.println("Su saldo actual es de: " + getSuma()); break;
            case 4:
                getRetirar();
                System.out.println("Su saldo actual es de: " + getResta());break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Gracias por su visita, vuelva pronto. ");break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No existe la opcion, intente de nuevo. ");break;
        }
    } while (opcion2 < 1 || opcion2 > 5);
}
}
```

En el main es donde me aparece el error:

```
package paquete_1;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int opcion2, menu;


    do {
        opcion2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bienvenido/a a BankMex" + "\nPorfavor seleccione una opción: " + "\n1. Tarejta de credito." + "\n2. Tarejta de débito." + "\n3. Cuenta de ahorro." + "\n4. Salir."));
        switch (opcion2) {
            
            //Intento llamar el metodo operaciones de la clase TarjetaDebido
            case 1: TarjetaDebito ob2=new TarjetaDebito(String nombre, String apellido, String curp, String direccion);
                     ob2.operaciones(); break;

            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Gracias por su visita, regrese pronto. ");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error, intente de nuevo. ");
                break;
        }
    } while (opcion2 < 1 || opcion2 > 4);       
}
}
```

Y tengo que aplicar herencia, me lo pidieron obligatorio.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: adjunta la clase cuentaBase, segura que debes aplicar herencia??

Comment: Como primer consejo, si vas utilizar herencia debes declarar con el modificador abstract tu clase de la cual heredaran, y en dicha clase podrías tener tus metodos abstratos, dicho esto ultimo deberías colocar tus implementaciones en la(s) clase(s) concreta(s) que hereden de esta por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te he editado los 3 archivos y a mí no me da ningún error actualmente, si te da algún error házmelo saber en los comentarios, al igual que si necesitas alguna aclaración de lo que he cambiado, por supuesto, házmelo saber también, si te da error, en un comentario ponme el error que te da.

**CLASE MAIN**

```
package paquete_1;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int opcion2, menu;


        do {
            opcion2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bienvenido/a a BankMex" + "\nPorfavor seleccione una opción: " + "\n1. Tarejta de credito." + "\n2. Tarejta de débito." + "\n3. Cuenta de ahorro." + "\n4. Salir."));
            switch (opcion2) {
                
                //Intento llamar el metodo operaciones de la clase TarjetaDebido
                case 1: 
                    TarjetaDebito ob2 = new TarjetaDebito();
                    ob2.operaciones(); 
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Gracias por su visita, regrese pronto. ");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Error, intente de nuevo. ");
                    break;
            }
        } while (opcion2 < 1 || opcion2 > 4);       
    }

}
```

**CLASE CUENTABASE**

```
package paquete_1;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class CuentaBase {
    
    protected double depositar;
    private int opcion;
    protected String nombre, apellido, curp, direccion;
    private double suma, resta;
    private double retirar, montoActual = 1000;
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    public CuentaBase() {
        
    }
    public CuentaBase(String nombre, String apellido, String curp, String direccion) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.curp = curp;
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }
    
       public void leerDatos() {
        System.out.print("Ingrese sus datos: ");
        System.out.print("Nombre: ");
        nombre = entrada.nextLine();      
        System.out.print("Apellido: ");
        apellido = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.print("CURP: ");
        curp = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Direccion: ");
        direccion = entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Sus datos han sido ingresados correctamente, regrese pronto. ");
        direccion = entrada.nextLine();
    }
    
    public double getmontoActual() {
        return montoActual;
    }
    
    public double getDepositar() {
        System.out.print("Cuanto desea depositar?: ");
        depositar = entrada.nextDouble();
        return depositar;
    }
    
    public double getRetirar() {
        System.out.println("Digite lo que desea retirar. ");
        retirar = entrada.nextDouble();
        return retirar;
    }
    
    public double getResta() {
        resta = montoActual - retirar;
        return resta;
    }
    
    public double getSuma() {
        suma = montoActual + depositar;
        return suma;
    }
    
    public double getsumaInteres() {
        System.out.println("Tiene un monto de saldo negativo: " + -montoActual * 1.15);
        return montoActual;
    }
    
    public double getinvertir() {
        System.out.println("Tiene un monto de: " + montoActual * 1.10);
        return montoActual;
    } 
}
```

**CLASE TARJETADEBITO**

```
package paquete_1;
public class TarjetaDebito extends CuentaBase {
    private int opcion2;
    
    public TarjetaDebito() {
    }
    public TarjetaDebito(String nombre, String apellido, String curp, String direccion) {
        super(nombre, apellido, curp, direccion);
     
    }
    //Metodo que intento llamar al main
    public void operaciones () {
        do {
            System.out.println("Porfavor seleccione una opción:");
            System.out.println("    1. Ver monto actual: ");
            System.out.println("    2. Abrir una tarjeta de credito");
            System.out.println("    3. Depositar");
            System.out.println("    4. Retirar");
            System.out.println("    5. Salir");
            opcion2 = entrada.nextInt();
            switch (opcion2) {
                case 1: getmontoActual();break;
                case 2: 
                    CuentaBase ob1= new CuentaBase(nombre, apellido, curp, direccion);
                    ob1.leerDatos(); break;

                case 3: getDepositar();
                    System.out.println("Su saldo actual es de: " + getSuma()); break;
                case 4:
                    getRetirar();
                    System.out.println("Su saldo actual es de: " + getResta());break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Gracias por su visita, vuelva pronto. ");break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("No existe la opcion, intente de nuevo. ");break;
            }
        } while (opcion2 < 1 || opcion2 > 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias!!, me ha funcionado!!.

Answer (score 0):

El error se da, por que en tu clase TarjetaDebito, creaste un Constructor, el cual tiene 4 parametros, si requieres usar el new TarjetaDebito(), tienes que declararlo.

```
public class TarjetaDebito extends CuentaBase {
private int opcion2;
/*Constructor default*/
public TarjetaDebito(){}
/*Fin Constructor default*/

public TarjetaDebito(String nombre, String apellido, String curp, String direccion) {
    super(nombre, apellido, curp, direccion);
 
}
//Metodo que intento llamar al main
public void operaciones () {
    do {
        System.out.println("Porfavor seleccione una opción:");
        System.out.println("    1. Ver monto actual: ");
        System.out.println("    2. Abrir una tarjeta de credito");
        System.out.println("    3. Depositar");
        System.out.println("    4. Retirar");
        System.out.println("    5. Salir");
        opcion2 = entrada.nextInt();
        switch (opcion2) {
            case 1: getmontoActual();break;
            case 2: 
                CuentaBase ob1= new CuentaBase(nombre, apellido, curp, direccion);
                ob1.leerDatos(); break;

            case 3: getDepositar();
                System.out.println("Su saldo actual es de: " + getSuma()); break;
            case 4:
                getRetirar();
                System.out.println("Su saldo actual es de: " + getResta());break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Gracias por su visita, vuelva pronto. ");break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No existe la opcion, intente de nuevo. ");break;
        }
    } while (opcion2 < 1 || opcion2 > 5);
}
}
```

Israel Ramos

Comment: Hola,  muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo acabo de realizar pero aun me salta error.

Answer (score 0):

El error es por que desde el main no necesitas enviar el tipo de dato junto al valor que estás enviando, o envías el valor explícitamente, por ejemplo: “Juan” o envías una variable que contendrá el valor, por ejemplo : nombre , pero no : String nombre

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).